# Heroku+Django+Postgres error: "FATAL: database "python_getting_started" does not exist"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to do the Getting Started with Python exercise at Heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction). I'm just following the instructions and using the git repo that was provided in the tutorial. But when I go to the /db page of the web app, which uses database functionality, I get this error trace:

---

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:5000/db

Django Version: 1.8.1
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'hello')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/Lisha/Desktop/Starred_Docs/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/Lisha/Desktop/Starred_Docs/python-getting-started/hello/views.py" in db
  14.     greeting.save()
File "/Users/Lisha/Desktop/Starred_Docs/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  710.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/Users/Lisha/Desktop/Starred_Docs/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  735.         with transaction.atomic(using=using, savepoint=False):
File "/Users/Lisha/Desktop/Starred_Docs/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in __enter__
  150.             if not connection.get_autocommit():
File "/Users/Lisha/Desktop/Starred_Docs/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in get_autocommit
  286.         self.ensure_connection()
File "/Users/Lisha/Desktop/Starred_Docs/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in ensure_connection
  130.                 self.connect()
File "/Users/Lisha/Desktop/Starred_Docs/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  97.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/Users/Lisha/Desktop/Starred_Docs/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in ensure_connection
  130.                 self.connect()
File "/Users/Lisha/Desktop/Starred_Docs/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py" in connect
  119.         self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "/Users/Lisha/Desktop/Starred_Docs/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py" in get_new_connection
  172.         connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "/Users/Lisha/Desktop/Starred_Docs/python-getting-started/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py" in connect
  164.     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /db
Exception Value: FATAL:  database "python_getting_started" does not exist
```

---

The crash is only when I run the app locally; the app on herokuapp.com works fine. Do you have any idea what the problem might be? Help would truly be appreciated.

Comment: show DATABASES from your  settings

Comment: @madzohan
DATABASES 
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django_postgrespool',
             'HOST': 'localhost',
             'NAME': 'python_getting_started',
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': u'********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC',
             'USER': ''}}

Comment: hm I've not used django_postgrespool engine, but anyway check if you have python_getting_started database at all:  **psql -l | grep '^ python_getting_started\b'**

Comment: I think I didn't have the database but I just created it by running "create database python_getting_started;". But it's not configured properly and it doesn't contain the same data as the remote database.

I just realized that in the tutorial, it says that the functionality should work if I append "/db" to the remote URL (the app on herokuapp.com); it doesn't say that it should work locally. But is there a way to get it to work locally like it does remotely? And to use the remote database rather than a local one?

Comment: **python manage.py migrate**

Comment: **python manage.py createsuperuser --username root --email your@gmail.com**

Comment: anyway if you have additional questions seems we should move to chat, cuse it is inappropriate

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #try to load local_settings.py if it exists
> try:
>     from .settings_local import *
> except Exception as e:
>     DATABASES = {
>         "default": {
>             "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
>         }
>     }
>     import dj_database_url
>     DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
>     # Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
>     SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
>     # Allow all host headers
>     ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['']
> ```

create `settings_local.py` near your `settings.py` and declare your DATABASE settings here

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'python_getting_started',
        'USER': 'some_postgre_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'some_password',
    }
}
```

If you don't have `python_getting_started` obviously you have to create it:

```
psql postgres
create database python_getting_started;
create user some_postgre_user password 'some_password';
grant all on database python_getting_started to some_postgre_user;
\q
```